# Filter data of an array in setState in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

In the code below, I am trying to make an array and remove duplicates from  array with reactjs:
The array called names is set in state:

```
this.state = {
    names = []
}
```

How can I remove the duplicated names and place them into the array

```
const data = [
    {
        "obj": {
            "no": "1",
            "info": [
                {
                    "name": "maya"
                },
                {
                    "name": "mina"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "obj": {
            "no": "2",
            "info": [

                {
                    "name": "maya"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "obj": {
            "no": "3",
            "info": [
                {
                    "name": "mina"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Mike"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
data.map((elem) => {
    for(let i = 0 ; i < elem.info.length;i++){
        let name_info = elem.info[i].name
            this.setState({
                names: [...this.state.names, name_info]
             })
    }
      })
```

expected output :["maya","mina",Mike]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're fan of one line

```
[...(new Set(data.map(d => d['obj']['info']).flat().map(info => info['name'])))]
```

Step by step explanation:

First `map` takes the input returns only info part of each entry:

`data.map(d => d['obj']['info'])` yields array of array containing info.

`[[{ name: "maya" }, { name: "mina" }], [{ name: "maya" }], [{ name: "mina" }, { name: "Mike" }]]`

`flat()` takes the input from previous map which is the array of array and yields array of elements, so it becomes

`[{ name: "maya" }, { name: "mina" }, { name: "maya" }, { name: "mina" }, { name: "Mike" }]`

`map()` takes the input from previous flat which is array of object (which contains `name`) and returns array of `name` value.

So you got `[ "maya", "mina", "maya", "mina", "Mike" ]`

The final array is given to `Set`, by definition set cannot contain same element more than one. Set of previous array is `[ "maya", "mina", "Mike" ]`.

As final step, set is converted to the array by using spread operator.

Comment: Thanks @sardok for your answer,can you explain a bit more about your code?

Comment: Added an explanation @Maya.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
    {
        "obj": {
            "no": "1",
            "info": [
                {
                    "name": "maya"
                },
                {
                    "name": "mina"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "obj": {
            "no": "2",
            "info": [

                {
                    "name": "maya"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "obj": {
            "no": "3",
            "info": [
                {
                    "name": "mina"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Mike"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
];

let names = [];

data.forEach(item => {
  Object.values(item)[0].info.forEach(person => {
    if(names.indexOf(person.name) === -1)
    {
      names.push(person.name)
    }
  })
})

console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
  "obj": {
    "no": "1",
    "info": [{
      "name": "maya"
    }, {
      "name": "mina"
    }]
  }
}, {
  "obj": {
    "no": "2",
    "info": [{
      "name": "maya"
    }]
  }
}, {
  "obj": {
    "no": "3",
    "info": [{
      "name": "mina"
    }, {
      "name": "Mike"
    }]
  }
}]

const names = data.flatMap(obj => obj.obj.info.map(info => info.name));
const unique = names.filter((name, i) => names.indexOf(name) === i);
console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you

First, this is a helper function to get just the unique value of an array

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

And, this is how can get the result you want

```
const newNames = data.map((elem) => elem.obj.info.map(info => info.name)).flat().filter(onlyUnique)
```

You can then use it like this

```
this.setState({
   names: [...this.state.names, ...newNames]
})
```